# Change all the label icon in a panel

Tags: java, swing

I have a panel with several JLabel, I would like to change all their Icon,

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");

for (int x=0;x< 21;x++) {
    javax.swing.JLabel lab = boardPanel.getComponent(x).;
    lab.setIcon(new ImageIcon(path + "\\image\\blank.jpg"));
}
```

it gives me an error of incompatible type, all inside the boardPanel are JLabel,
im using netbeans 6.8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getComponent()` will return a Component. You'll need to cast to a `JLabel`.

```
javax.swing.JLabel lab = (javax.swing.JLabel)boardPanel.getComponent(x);
```

For safety's sake you should check the expected type before casting. After all, at some stage you may have types in there other than `JLabel`s.

```
Component c = boardPanel.getComponent(x);
if (c instanceof JLabel) {
   JLabel lab = (JLabel)c;
   // etc.
}
```

Comment: No problem. That's what we're here for :-)

Comment: @Josh How about accepting the answer if it works, otherwise it will be listed unanswered.